# R: If name includes specific text, then group it

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping, contains

I am using Energy Performance Certificate Data to identify the heating fuel types of buildings in an area however, they are split into over 60 different subsets of 9 main fuel types. I would like add another column for fuel type so that they can be grouped by the 9 main fuel types.

An example of the relevant columns of the data is:

```
BuildingID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

MainHeatDesc <- c("Boiler and radiators, mains gas", "Boiler and radiators, oil", "Room heaters, electric", "Room heaters, LPG", "Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric", "Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric", "Ground source heat pump, mains gas", "Electric storage heaters", "Room heaters, wood logs", "Boilers and radiators, wood chips")

data <- data.frame(BuildingID, MainHeatDesc)
```

This is a small example taking some of the subsets of the original data. In this example I would like to create another column for main fuel type grouping them as: Mains gas, Oil, Electric, LPG and wood.

The end result should look like this:

```
# BuildingID            MainHeatDesc                             MainFuelType
#     1       Boiler and radiators, mains gas                      Mains gas
#     2       Boiler and radiators, oil                              Oil
#     3       Room heaters, electric                               Electric
#     4       Room heaters, LPG                                      LPG 
#     5       Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric   Electric
#     6       Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric       Electric
#     7       Ground source heat pump, mains gas                   Mains Gas
#     8       Electric storage heaters                             Electric
#     9       Room heaters, wood logs                                Wood
#    10       Boilers and radiators, wood chips                      Wood
```

If anyone is able to help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any queries or need any more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar logic as @tmfmnk but in base R using `sub`.

```
types <- c('Mains Gas', 'Oil', 'Electric', 'LPG', 'Wood')
data$MainFuelType <- sub(paste0(".*(?i)(", paste0("\\b", types, "\\b", 
                        collapse = "|"), ").*"), "\\1", data$MainHeatDesc)

data
#   BuildingID                                       MainHeatDesc MainFuelType
#1           1                    Boiler and radiators, mains gas    mains gas
#2           2                          Boiler and radiators, oil          oil
#3           3                             Room heaters, electric     electric
#4           4                                  Room heaters, LPG          LPG
#5           5 Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric     electric
#6           6     Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric     electric
#7           7                 Ground source heat pump, mains gas    mains gas
#8           8                           Electric storage heaters     Electric
#9           9                            Room heaters, wood logs         wood
#10         10                  Boilers and radiators, wood chips         wood
```

where the regex which is generated dynamically looks like :

```
paste0(".*(?i)(", paste0("\\b", types, "\\b", collapse = "|"), ").*")
#[1] ".*(?i)(\\bMains Gas\\b|\\bOil\\b|\\bElectric\\b|\\bLPG\\b|\\bWood\\b).*"
```

where `(?i)` is for case-insensitivity.

Comment: This worked!! I am unsure why this worked and @tmfmnk answer didn't though. Not the easiest answer to follow so if you could explain some of the terms in the sub that would be great. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @EllisR8 We are pasting all the `types` in `sub` with word boundaries (`\\b`) which generates a pattern as shown at the end of my answer. The extra `?i` is added to include case-insensitivity so that `gas` is matched as well as `Gas`. The `\\1` is used to capture any value which is present in `type` from `data$MainHeatDesc`.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `stringr` option could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate(group = str_extract(MainHeatDesc, regex("\\bMains gas|\\bOil|\\bElectric|\\bLPG|\\bwood", ignore_case = TRUE)))

   BuildingID                                       MainHeatDesc     group
1           1                    Boiler and radiators, mains gas mains gas
2           2                          Boiler and radiators, oil       oil
3           3                             Room heaters, electric  electric
4           4                                  Room heaters, LPG       LPG
5           5 Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric  electric
6           6     Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric  electric
7           7                 Ground source heat pump, mains gas mains gas
8           8                           Electric storage heaters  Electric
9           9                            Room heaters, wood logs      wood
10         10                  Boilers and radiators, wood chips      wood
```

If you have a lot of patterns, then you can prepare it as:

```
x <- paste(paste0("\\b", c("Mains gas", "Oil", "Electric", "LPG", "wood"), "\\b"), collapse = "|")

data %>%
 mutate(group = str_extract(MainHeatDesc, regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

If you want to further match your expected output, then you can use a replacement vector:

```
y <- c("Mains gas", "Oil", "Electric", "LPG", "Wood")

data %>%
 mutate(group = str_extract(MainHeatDesc, regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE)),
        group = str_replace(group, regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE), y))

   BuildingID                                       MainHeatDesc     group
1           1                    Boiler and radiators, mains gas Mains gas
2           2                          Boiler and radiators, oil       Oil
3           3                             Room heaters, electric  Electric
4           4                                  Room heaters, LPG       LPG
5           5 Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric      Wood
6           6     Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric Mains gas
7           7                 Ground source heat pump, mains gas       Oil
8           8                           Electric storage heaters  Electric
9           9                            Room heaters, wood logs       LPG
10         10                  Boilers and radiators, wood chips      Wood
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply! I have tried the second method you posted however it is giving all values in the new column as "<chr[1]>". Do you know why this is?

Comment: It's hard to tell, try to use the newest version of `dplyr` and `stringr`.

Comment: I have noticed that there it returns <chr[1]> when there is a match, <chr[0]> when there is no match found (ie. alternate fuel) and <chr[2]> when there the description includes multiple fuel types. This is proving difficult due to the large number of groups.

Comment: Use `str_extract` instead.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you should use `str_extract()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is by using nested `ifelse`statements and `grepl`, which matches a regex pattern:

```
data$MainFuelType <- ifelse(grepl("mains gas", data$MainHeatDesc), "Mains gas",
                        ifelse(grepl("\\boil", data$MainHeatDesc), "Oil",
                               ifelse(grepl("(e|E)lectric", data$MainHeatDesc), "Electric",
                                      ifelse(grepl("LPG", data$MainHeatDesc), "LPG", "Wood"))))
```

Result:

```
data
   BuildingID                                       MainHeatDesc MainFuelType
1           1                    Boiler and radiators, mains gas    Mains gas
2           2                          Boiler and radiators, oil          Oil
3           3                             Room heaters, electric     Electric
4           4                                  Room heaters, LPG          LPG
5           5 Air source heat pump, underfloor heating, electric     Electric
6           6     Air source heat pump, fan coil units, electric     Electric
7           7                 Ground source heat pump, mains gas    Mains gas
8           8                           Electric storage heaters     Electric
9           9                            Room heaters, wood logs         Wood
10         10                  Boilers and radiators, wood chips         Wood
```